# How to find the most frequent digit in a number string?

Tags: java

/*I am a beginner in programming.As a part of an assignment, I have to find the most frequent digit in a number string.Though my code gets compiled, it doesn't give me the correct results.Please help me with this.
*/

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class program
    {
    public int test(String number)
    {
    int freq0,freq1,freq2,freq3,freq4,freq5,freq6,freq7,freq8,freq9;
    freq0=0;
    freq1=0;
    freq2=0;
    freq3=0;
    freq4=0;
    freq5=0;
    freq6=0;
    freq7=0;
    freq8=0;
    freq9=0;
    for (int i =0; i<number.length();i++)
    {
        switch (number.charAt(i))
        {
            case 48: freq0++;
            break;
            case 49: freq1++;
            break;
            case 50: freq2++;
            break;
            case 51: freq3++;
            break;
            case 52: freq4++;
            break;
            case 53: freq5++;
            break;
            case 54: freq6++;
            break;
            case 55: freq7++;
            break;
            case 56: freq8++;
            break;
            case 57: freq9++;
            break;
        }
    }
    List<Integer> hope = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    hope.add(freq0);
    hope.add(freq1);
    hope.add(freq2);
    hope.add(freq3);
    hope.add(freq4);
    hope.add(freq5);
    hope.add(freq6);
    hope.add(freq7);
    hope.add(freq8);
    hope.add(freq9);

    int temp=0;
    for (int j=0; j<(hope.size());j++)
    {
        if (temp<hope.get(j))
        {
            temp=hope.get(j);
        }
    }

    return temp;
    }
    }
```

//this class is called by another main class.I am writing it's code too.

```
    public class checker
    {
    public static void main ( String args [])
    {
    int inputs[] = {1234, 11, 144, 97764 };
    int outputs[] = {1, 1, 4, 7};

    for(int i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        int input=inputs[i];
        int oracle_output=outputs[i];

        program p = new program();

        String input_string = "" + input;
        int output = p.test(input_string);
        if(output==oracle_output) {
            System.out.println("test passed for " + input);
        } else {
            System.out.println("test failed for " + input);
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What result are you getting, and what do you expect? Which number is failing? Have you stepped through it with a debugger? I'd strongly suggest reformatting your code to make it easier to read, by the way. (Your main code can be a lot simpler too, but it's worth understanding the current failure before simplifying it.)

Comment: You can make your code much more readable, if you replace `48,49,50` etc. in the switch-case with `'0', '1', '2'` etc. And stick to the Java Naming conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html, e.g. Classes should start with a uppercase letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is just use a simple array.

```
long number = 12345612;
int []frequency = new int[10];
while(number > 0)
{
 int digit = number % 10;
 number /= 10;
 frequency[digit] ++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
 System.out.println(frequency[i]);
```

---

If it is a `String`.

```
String str = "12342352397235823050237238523";
int []frequency = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
{
 int digit = str.charAt(i) - '0';
 frequency[digit] ++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
 System.out.println(frequency[i]);
```

To get the maximum occuring digit.

```
int maxFrequency = 0;
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
   if(frequency[i] > maxFrequency){
     maxFrequency = frequency[i];
     index = i;
    }
  }
System.out.println("The highest occuring digit is " + index + " occuring " + maxFrequency + " times(s)");
```

The mistake in your program was that you're not considering the digit which repeated many times, you're taking into account the number of times only. And hence you get only the frequency not the digit.

Answer (score 0):

Like it is said in the comment, the code can be made simpler (and more readable) 
However, the answer to your question is this: the return value (temp) is the frequency of the most frequent digit, instead of the digit itself (which is j, you hust need to "remember" it)

Answer (score 0):

Here is more readable and simpler code:

```
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;

            public class MostFrequentDigits1 {

                /**
                 * @param args
                 */
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    long number = 12345612;
                    String str = "12342352397235823050237238523";
                    getMostFrequentDigitWInNumber(number);
                    getMostFrequentDigitInString(str);

                }

                public static void getMostFrequentDigitWInNumber(long number) {
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    int[] frequency = new int[10];
                    int mostFrequentVal = 0;
                    while (number > 0) {
                        int digit = (int) (number % 10);
                        number /= 10;
                        frequency[digit]++;
                        if (frequency[digit] > mostFrequentVal) {
                            mostFrequentVal = frequency[digit];
                        }
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < frequency.length; j++) {
                        if (frequency[j] == mostFrequentVal) {
                            list.add(j);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("most frequent digits in Number:" + list);
                }

                public static void getMostFrequentDigitInString(String str) {
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    int mostFrequentVal = 0;
                    int[] frequency = new int[10];
                    for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++) {
                        char c = str.charAt(k);
                        int ind = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(c));
                        frequency[ind]++;
                        if (frequency[ind] > mostFrequentVal) {
                            mostFrequentVal = frequency[ind];
                        }
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < frequency.length; j++) {
                        if (frequency[j] == mostFrequentVal) {

                            list.add(j);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("most frequent digits in string:" + list);
                }

            }
```